# Local diffeomorphism preserves orientation if and only if the jacobian is positive everywhere

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Consider the following problem from *Curves and Surfaces*, 2nd Edition, by Montiel and Ros:

[image]

To me, the solution is pretty much straightforward, following directly from the definitions. My question is?

> Where is the connectedness hypothesis used?